# Sharepoint CAML best practices

Tags: caml, best-practices

Can I write a CAML query inside a `for loop`?

*Copied from comment*

I have a funds list which displays funds and user name. I have populated a `DataTable` into a `GridView` and able to display all the data perfectly. Now I need to add 4 columns and need to add user details {ph,address,name and guid }. So while I loop in the `DataTable`, I check the row with user name and then query the Users list. I was thinking if its ok/best practice to write a CAML query inside a for loop

```
    fundEPTable = new DataTable();
        query.Query = querynine;
        FundDataCollection = listFunds.GetItems(query);
        if (FundDataCollection.Count > 0 && FundDataCollection != null)
        {
            fundEPTable = FundDataCollection.GetDataTable();
            fundsTableView = fundEPTable.DefaultView;
            fundsTableView.Sort = "FundName ASC";
            fundEPTable = fundsTableView.ToTable();


            for (int i = 0; i < fundEPTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (fundEPTable.Rows[i]["CurrentComp"].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    fundEPTable.Rows[i]["CurrentComp"] = "No";
                }
                else
                {
                    fundEPTable.Rows[i]["CurrentComp"] = "Yes";
                }

                if (fundEPTable.Rows[i]["CurrentSci"].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    fundEPTable.Rows[i]["CurrentSci"] = "No";
                }
                else
                {
                    fundEPTable.Rows[i]["CurrentSci"] = "Yes";
                }

                if (fundEPTable.Rows[i]["GUID"].ToString() !=null)
                {
                    string guid = fundEPTable.Rows[i]["GUID"].ToString();
                    SPList Admin = web.Lists["ListName"];
                    SPQuery queryAdmin = new SPQuery();
                    queryAdmin.Query = "myquery";
                    SPListItemCollection collAdmin = Admin.GetItems(queryAdmin);
                    if (collAdmin.Count > 0 && collAdmin !=null)
                    {
                        fundEPTable.Rows[i]["Address"] = collAdmin[0]["Address"].ToString();
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a funds list which displays funds and user name . I have populated a datatable into a gridview and able to display all the data perfectly . Now i need to add 4 columns and need to add user details {ph,address,name and guid } . So while i loop in the data table ,i check the row with user name and then query the Users list . I was thinking if its ok/best practise to write a caml query inside a for loop :(

Answer (score 3):

In your case you need to find whether the item exists or not, so there is no problem with invoking the CAML for each check.

Another approach is to form a dynamic query based on the number of rows to validate, for example if you want to validate 3 rows of data then form a query in with condition like

```
<Or>
<Or>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="UserName"/><Value Type="Text">UserNameInRow1</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="UserName"/><Value Type="Text">UserNameInRow2</Value>
    </Eq>
</Or>
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="UserName"/><Value Type="Text">UserNameInRow3</Value>
</Eq>
</Or>
```

Then check in the return `SPListItemCollection` and make sure the row exists. This approach requires only one database call as opposed to 'N', where 'N' is the number of rows to validate.

Comment: i have put the code for better understanding . I write a caml query get details . Further loop in each item and write another query . Does this approach acceptable wrt coding practise ?

Comment: The best practice is, using a loop create a dynamic CAML query from the table `fundEPTable`. Then create an in-memory list which states whether the username exists. Then inside your current loop, you just need to check `inmemorylist.Contains(guidPwC)` instead of `if (collAdmin.Count > 0 && collAdmin !=null)`